# Execute DB2 iSeries Stored Procedure from a SQL 2005 Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, db2, linked-server, ibm-midrange

I am trying to execute a stored procedured from a linked database in MS SQL 2005.  The linked database is a db2 database on a iseries server.  I am using the iSeries IBMDASQL service provider.  I am able to query the stored procedure without problems using a simple vbscript and ado.  When I try to execute the same stored procedure in query analyzer on the SQL Server, I never see any results.  Query analyzer always show 'command executed' and when I execute the select * on the temp table, no values appear.  What am I doing wrong?????
Thanks!

--code from query analyzer below--

```
DECLARE @emailToAddress         char(50)
DECLARE @emailFromAddress       char(50)

set @emailToAddress = 'customer.service@company.com'
set @emailFromAddress = 'customer@gmail.com'

If Object_ID('tempdb..#tmpResultTbl') Is Not Null
    Drop Table #tmpResultTbl

Create Table #tmpResultTbl
(
OUTPGMID Char(150))

--SET FMTONLY Off
Set NoCount On
Insert Into #tmpResultTbl 
EXEC ('CALL abicqual.VP_GETCCEPGMID(?, ?) ', @emailToAddress, @emailFromAddress) AT MAM400 

Select * From #tmpResultTbl
```

UPDATED:
Here is the updated code to use openquery... still no luck :(

DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000)
DECLARE @emailToAddress         varchar(50)
DECLARE @emailFromAddress       varchar(50)
SET @emailToAddress = 'customer.service@company.com'
SET @emailFromAddress = 'customer@gmail.com'
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MAM400,''CALL abicqual.VP_GETCCEPGMID(''''' + @emailToAddress + ''''', ''''' + @emailFromAddress + '''''' + ')''' + ')'
Print @TSQL
EXEC (@TSQL)

--output below--
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MAM400,'CALL abicqual.VP_GETCCEPGMID(''customer.service@company.com'', ''customer@gmail.com'')')
Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot process the object "CALL abicqual.VP_GETCCEPGMID('customer.service@company.com', 'customer@gmail.com')". The OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "MAM400" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there are a number of issues with the IBMDASQL provider that I was using.  Believe it or not it is faster and more reliable to use the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers.  After creating a new linked server with this provider, all of my earlier sql attempts worked properly.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Microsoft DB2OLEDB provider which is available as part of the Feature Pack for SQL 2005 - April 2006.  It's also part of Host Integration Services.  It hooks into the AS/400 using the DRDA (Oracle style) protocol.

You can download it seperately but it will only install on SQL standard, enterprise or developer (not express).

I also find that building the complete query that I want to run on the DB2/400 box and then wrapping it in a VARCHAR(MAX) string which also includes the "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (--linkedservername--,--DB2/400 query with params--)" and then using the sp_execute or EXEC commands returns the best results.

It's even possible to wrap up RPG code within DB2/400 SQL procedures and then call them (with params) from the MS SQL Server and return any result set as a MS SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(SQL.90).aspx).  [This blog posting](http://blogs.conchango.com/jamespipe/archive/2007/06/28/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-Passing-variables-into-an-OPENQUERY-argument.aspx) shows an example of passing variables into an OPENQUERY statement.

Answer (score 0):

call oracle procedure (function) via linked server and get its result (return value)

```
--input parameters p1, p2, p3
declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
declare @param nvarchar(100)
declare @result varchar(20) -- numbers may cause data type error

-- (...custom actions, i.e. insert to local table)

set @SQL = N'set @result = (select * from openquery(myLinkedServer, ''select OwnerName.Function_Insert(' + cast(@p1 as varchar) + ', ' + cast(@p1 as varchar) + ', ' + cast(@p3 as varchar) + ') from dual''))'
set @param = '@result varchar output'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @param, @result output 

if @result  '0' goto ERROR

-- (...custom actions)

return 1 -- OK

ERROR:
-- (...custom actions, i.e. delete from local table with(rowlock))
return 0 -- KO
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add brackets around the call statement. You still won't be able to select into a table at SQL Server end though unless you have installed support for distributed transactions. I am not sure why it needs a transaction, but it won't work unless you have this set up.

EXEC ('{CALL abicqual.VP_GETCCEPGMID(?, ?)}', @emailToAddress, @emailFromAddress) AT MAM400